# To tell Eclipse environment variables

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I have simple application that uses so library that is located in another directory defined by command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/projects/myso/` in same terminal I run executable. Application runs fine in terminal window, but if I run it from Eclipse it doesn't finds required so library.

I use run profile configuration to set environment variable in section Environment:

```
Name: LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Value: ~/projects/myso/:~/projects/myOtherso/`
```

This not helps - `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How to tell Eclipse `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable?

Comment: Can you try to launch Eclipse from the terminal where `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is exported? That solved similar issues for me some other times. If it solves it. Then modify the `.desktop` file from Eclipse to be launched from the terminal (you can also tell the `.desktop` to not show the terminal)

Comment: I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in terminal and after run Eclipse. Actually strange, but got the same result. Library not loaded by executable.